# While less than or not equal to won't terminate

Tags: java, while-loop

I am programming a Pit scoring system and I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
while(highestConverted<scoreConverted||highestConverted!=scoreConverted)
```

It will always return true and repeat the code within it regardless of the value of scoreConverted or highestConverted. I don't think it really matters but both values or ints which are converted from scanner variables using Integer.parseInt . I don't have that much experience with Java but I do know some of the basics.

Comment: What's the question? You posted a fact.

Comment: This condition should only return false if `highestConverted == scoreConverted`, thus your while could be simplifyied...

Comment: if any one of them will return true, result will be true so you can go with and operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your code:

```
while(highestConverted<scoreConverted||highestConverted!=scoreConverted)
```

Let's suppose `highestConverted = 5` and `scoreConverted = 2`.

```
highestConverted <  2 =  5 < 2  -> false
highestConverted != 2 -> 5 != 2 -> true

false || true = true.
```

So the while loop will always repeat.

It should be

```
while(highestConverted<scoreConverted && highestConverted!=scoreConverted)
```

Or, better

```
while(highestConverted<scoreConverted)
```

`highestConverted<scoreConverted` implicitly includes `highestConverted!=scoreConverted` as it will stop at `scoreConverted - 1`.

Comment: Turns out that I was also forgetting to close my scanners.

Comment: @Benjamin Glad it helped! For scanners: it's good that you noticed it! Always close scanners/input streams/output streams when you don't need them anymore :)

Comment: Except now I get this error:Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at pit.ScoringSystem.main(ScoringSystem.java:17)

Comment: @Benjamin That's likely because you closed your `Scanner` before that line. **Note:** if you have more scanners initialized like `new Scanner(System.in)` they refer to the same `System.in`. If you close one, you will close all scanners at the same time.

Comment: Okay! But, it still seems to be returning true because the code within the while is still running.